# Play framework (1.2.5) - Is it possible to persistence two dimensional array in play framework?

Tags: java, arrays, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am working on a view where I wanna display an two dimensional arraylist `Object[][]`.
Is it possible to persistence this out of the box when using Play Framework?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        #{field 'object[0][0].variable'}
            <input type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}"/>
        #{/field}
    </td>
    <td>
        #{field 'object[1][0].variable'}
            <input type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}"/>
        #{/field}
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        #{field 'object[0][1].variable'}
            <input type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}"/>
        #{/field}
    </td>
    <td>
        #{field 'object[1][1].variable'}
            <input type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${field.value}"/>
        #{/field}
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Play with JPA then no. Arrays are not persisted with JPA.

You could create your own entity and encapsulate it in a list instead.